# View test result of BrowserTestBase based test?

Tags: 8, testing

How can I setup my Drupal config to be able to view the results of failed tests using the new BrowserTestBase class in 8.2.x?

I don't see any files generated and the phpunit.xml config does not seem to be getting respected:

```
<!-- Example BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY value: /path/to/webroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="/var/www/testing" />
```

The command I am using is:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit -c core/phpunit.xml --group tvi
```

I have some failing tests but I can't see what the test sees.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Before calling parent::setUp(), I set:

```
$this->htmlOutputEnabled = true;
```